# When a Child class is added to a List<parent>, is the child-specific data lost?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a function that makes a list of animals, some of which are dogs, and some of which are just animals.  That function returns that list to a different function that wants to extract out just the dogs, which is possible because the Animal class has a bool isDog.

**My question is, is it possible to extract the dog-specific(child-specific) data from the animal(parent) class, aka. can an animal still be a dog under the hood?**

Things I have tried:

- Extracting out the dogs using the isDog bool and then calling the Dog
  constructor to make a new one outside of the function that returns a
  list of animals
- Giving the dog class a constructor that takes in an animal, but still
  no way to preserve tail length

I have these two interfaces

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    string eyeColor;
    int numLegs;
}

public interface IDog: IAnimal
{
    double tailLength;
}
```

and these two implementations

```
public class Animal: IAnimal
{
    public string eyeColor{get;set}
    public int numLegs {get; set;}
    public bool isDog;

    public Animal(string eyes, int legs){
        this.eyeColor = eyes;
        this.numLegs = legs
        this.isDog = false;
    }
}

public class Dog: Animal, IDog
{
    public double tailLength {get;set;}
    public Dog(double tail, string eyes)
    {
        this.tailLength = tail;
        this.eyeColor = eyes;
        this.numLegs = 4;
        this.isDog = true;
    }
}
```

and this is the current state of the two functions

```
List<Animal> getAnimals()
{
    List<Animal> animals;
    Animal a1 = new Animal("Blue", 4);
    animals.Add(a1);
    Animal a2 = new Animal("Green", 2);
    animals.Add(a2);
    Dog d1 = new Dog(2.3, "Brown");
    animals.Add(d1);
    Dog d2 = new Dog(3.5, "Black");
    animals.Add(d2);
    return animals;
}

void foo(){
    IEnumerable<IAnimal> sample = getAnimals();
    var x = totalTailLength(sample.Where(d => d.isDog));
}

double totalTailLength(IEnumerable<IDog> dogs){
    return dogs.Sum(d => d.tailLength);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You might want to take a look at the "is" and "as" keywords in C# which can be very helpful when testing for types or casting between types

Comment: As written, your code would not even compile!

Comment: Also, you don't respect .NET nomenclature (Pascal casing for functions and properties)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely do that. And if you use your exact code and fix a few errors, then you could see that it works:

1. There are two syntax errors where you missed a semicolon.
2. Fields cannot be interface members, so you need to make them properties.
3. `Dog` needs to call the parent’s constructor, which also removes the need to set those properties manually:

   ```
   public Dog(double tail, string eyes) : base(eyes, 4)
   {
       this.tailLength = tail;
       this.isDog = true;
   }
   ```
4. In `getAnimals`, you need to initialize the list:

   ```
   List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();
   ```
5. In `foo`, `sample` is of type `IEnumerable<IAnimal>`, so the elements are of type `IAnimal`. That type however does not have the `isDog` property (since it’s on the class but not on the interface). So either change the type to `IEnumerable<Animal>`, or move the member to the interface.
6. `totalTailLength` expects an enumerable of `IDog`s but `sample.Where()` returns `IAnimal`s (or `Animal`s as per above). Since you filtered the elements, you should cast the enumerable:

   ```
   var x = totalTailLength(sample.Where(d => d.isDog).Cast<IDog>());
   ```

And then everything will compile and—if you actually print out the results—you get the correct results.

The type of an object is not attached to the variable that references that object but to the object itself. So every `Dog` inside your animal list still knows that it’s a dog. And that actually allows you to get rid of the `isDog` member since you can just check whether an object is of a specific type using the [`is` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx):

```
IAnimal someAnimal = new Dog();
bool isADog = someAnimal is Dog; // true
```

And you can also use that with LINQ to filter for `Dog` elements of your `IAnimal` list using [`Enumerable.OfType<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
var x = totalTailLength(sample.OfType<IDog>());
```

Comment: thanks poke, first time using C# and this was very helpful

Answer (score 5):

No, of course the data specific to child class are not lost.

But please :

- define your instance variable as private and provide a public property
- remove the variable isDog !This is an error in your conception. Tomorrow, if you create class Cat, Mouse, Duck, will you add instance variables isCat, isMouse, isDuck ?

If you need to extract only Dog animals, you can simply use Linq :

```
IEnumerable<IDog> dogs = animals.OfType<IDog>();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that.  This:

```
sample.Where(d => d.isDog)
```

will return an `IEnumerable<Animal>`, because that's the that's what the type is in your collection.  The data is not 'lost', but you're working with `Animal` types, that don't know about your `Dog` properties.

You want to actually get the `Dog` types out of your collection, like:

```
sample.OfType<Dog>()
```

If you debug your code, you can look at the underlying properties at runtime in the debugger.  Give that a try and you can see the real types in your collection.

Answer (score 3):

No data is lost. The class doesn't stop being a Dog. All you have to do is cast it back to its child type, and the data will be there waiting for you.